# How can I use HTTP POST requests to insert a new event from a chrome extension, using google calendar api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, request, google-calendar-api

Due to CORS I have not been able to use the js libraries, so my alternative is to use fetch to create http requests. When I try to send the POST request with the data of the new event, the console throws me this error:

[www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events:1](http://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events:1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

```
Object
error:
code: 400
errors: Array(1)
0: {domain: "global", reason: "badRequest", message: "Bad Request"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
message: "Bad Request"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

This is my code:

```
var evento = {
  'summary': 'Test',
  'location': 'A random place',
  'description': 'A random description',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2021-04-30T09:00:00-07:00Z',
    'timeZone': 'America/Mexico_City'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2021-04-30T17:00:00-07:00Z',
    'timeZone': 'America/Mexico_City'
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
  'attendees': [
    { 'email': 'test1@gmail.com' },
    { 'email': 'test213@gmail.com' }
  ],
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': false,
    'overrides': [
      { 'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60 },
      { 'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10 }
    ]
  }
};

  
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ 'interactive': true }, function(token) {
  console.log(token)
  var init = { 
    'method' : 'POST',
    'async'  : true,
    'headers': {
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(evento)
  };

  

  fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events', init)
  .then((response) => response.json()) // Transform the data into json
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
})
```

And this is the manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Coffee Test",
  "description": "Another attempt to make this thing work!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": { "128": "128-icon.png" },
  "key": "YOUR_CHROME_KEY",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.random.net/*"],
      "exclude_matches": [
        "*://*.random.net/*/results/*"
      ],
      "js": ["background.js", "jquery-3.3.1.min.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
            "jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
            "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Extensión Test1"
},
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "identity", "https://apis.google.com/", "*://*.random.net/*"],
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "YOUR_CLIENT_CODE",
      "scopes": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
      ]
  }   
}
```

I have no problems with GET, only with POST requests
I have already checked the official documentation, but i'm still confused about what is my error in the request

Comment: I got a 404 - "requested URL [...] was not found" from Google after clicking on the link in your question.

Comment: Based on the response you're getting ([400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)) it seems that your request is invalid. The [documentation](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events) mentions that you also need the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events` scope to use this endpoint.

Comment: And add `https://www.googleapis.com/` to `permissions`.